# pandas unit test AssertionError: DataFrame.index are different

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I have this function that I want to test:

```
def filter_df(df, column_name: str, skill: List):
    return df.query(f"{column_name} in {skill}")
```

This is my test:

```
def test_filter_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["sap", "hi", "abc"], "col2": [3, 4, 4]})
    expected = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["hi", "abc"], "col2": [4, 4]})
    assert_frame_equal(filter_df(df, "col1", ["hi", "abc"]), expected)
```

I'm getting a `assert_frame_equal(filter_df(df, "col1", ["hi", "abc"]), expected)` error, but I don't see why the dataframes aren't identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the index in `filter_df`:

```
df.query(f"{column_name} in {skill}").reset_index(drop=True)
```

At the moment the returned DF has the original index of the given rows which in your case is 1,2 and not 0,1 as in the `expected` DF

Alternatively, if this is intended behavior of the function, edit the `expected` DF to have the correct index